# How to write columnwise in FORMAT in FORTRAN 77

Tags: fortran, fortran77, inout, ansys

I am using FORTRAN77 as a third party language on ANSYS computation software. Here we can write the entire row and columns to files during I/O operations. I am not able to however move the cursor to the first row and write column wise thereafter- for every column in the 2D array defined. It writes all the data in the single column unfortunately. I need to know what I can use at the place quoted as XXX
`*CFOPEN, ACT_STR, CSV,,APPEND
*DO,INF,1,2*S,1
 *VWRITE, S0(1,INF),
 (XXX,F10.2,',')
*CFCLOS`

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your question does not make much sense to me. FORMAT is not about cursor. It is about writing data in specific columns. Then you write one line after another. One line is typically written in one `write` statement. But you should try something yourself. This site is not really meant for tutorials. There are many tutorials about FORMAT on the web.

Answer (score 0):

You can try transpose of the matrix and then print the matrix row-wise. you can write a small subroutine that can do the transpose for SO.